# File name with double .cpp and .c

Tags: command-prompt

[![My file name .cpp and .c appears as .cpp.cpp and .c.c respectively.Due to this I need to compile typing .cpp or .c twice. So, is there anyway I could make it normal. ][1]]

Comment: Rename the files. And stop naming them that way in the first place. (And there was no need for an image to show a problem you can explain in words.)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the file, remove repeated extension. For example, filename.cpp.cpp